# What is a clean way to represent a bind in a uml diagram?

Tags: c++, boost, uml, boost-bind

I would like to represent the following code using a UML diagram:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>

using namespace std;

class A {
 public:
  void bar() {std::cout << "A::bar()" << std::endl;}
};

// FUNC should be callable with arguments (int, A*)
template <typename FUNC>
class B {
 public:
  B(FUNC func, int data) : func_(func), data_(data){}
  void operator()(A* ap){func_(data_, ap);}
  FUNC func_;
  int data_;
};

// object generator uses argument deduction to construct B
template <typename FUNC>
B<FUNC> makeB(FUNC func, int data) {
  return B<FUNC>(func, data);
}

struct F {
  static void apply(int a, int b, A* ap){
    std::cout << "a+b = " << a + b << std::endl;
    ap->bar();
  }
};

int main() {
  A* a = new A;
  auto b = makeB(boost::bind(F::apply, 10, _1, _2), 20);
  b(a);
}
```

Here is my [first attempt](http://i.imgur.com/vflKO9N). I think there is some room for improvement:

1. Should I capture pointers to `F` and `A` in the `bind` attributes or represent them serparately? Currently I'm showing both. I think the syntax for the `F::apply` attribute is also wrong.
2. What is the best way to write the signature template for the `bind` class?
3. Is there a better way to use `decltype` in `B`'s template parameter? currently it looks a bit clumsy.

The purpose is to communicate how `bind` works to people who may not be familiar with it and perhaps convey a little about how bind works internally. The diagram should be as simple as possible so any hacks that are intuitive and not misleading are okay, it doesn't have to conform precisely to the UML standard.

**update**: [This version](http://i.imgur.com/a30Llpf) fixes the type of `bind`'s internal function pointer.

Comment: [This](http://blog.think-async.com/2010/04/bind-illustrated.html) blog may provide some inspiration or direction.  It is one of the first references I recommend to people whom are trying to understand `bind`.

Comment: Thanks, that's a useful article, also I just fixed the type of the member function pointer